# performance tuning creating OrientDB (deBruijn Graph)

Tags: orientdb, graph-databases, orientdb-2.1, nosql

i have searched the Internet and also the manual for some performance tuning abilities to decrease the building time of my deBruijn Graph with OrientDB.
All following is dione in Java.

In OrientDB:
**Kmers** are indexed.
**Edges** are property based.

What i want to do is:

1. read in a **multiple sequence** file
2. split sequence in kmers
3. add Kmers to Database and create Edges between adjacent kmers

One and two are done already.
So when I add a kmer to OrientDB, i have to check if this kmer exist and if so i need the vertx to add a nwe edge.
Is there any fast way to do so?
I already created a local hash with kmer as key and OrientDB RID as value. But getting the vertex seems to need much time.

I already tried with:

```
OGlobalConfiguration.USE_WAL.setValue(false);
OGlobalConfiguration.TX_USE_LOG.setValue(false);
declareIntent(new OIntentMassiveInsert());
```

I need nearly 3 hours to add 256 kmers and 40.000.000 edges.
Also the size of the created DB is 9GB, the start file was 40 MB.
Any suggestions how to improve it?

Feel free to ask if something is not understandable.

Thanks a lot.

Michael

Edit:

do you have any experience with Record Grow factor?
I think the Node record have some in and out edge information by default in it. Could i increase the runtime with the RECORD_GROW_FACTOR? DO you have any experince with that?

Comment: Hi @Michael to check if a vertex already exist, and adding a new one if it doesn't, you can use the update/upsert command? did you try it?

Comment: Hi @Michela, i try to figure out what the return value of this command is. In the manual [link](http://orientdb.com/docs/2.2/SQL-Update.html) they wrote: "RETURN Specifies an expression to return instead of the record and what to do with the result-set returned by the expression..."  Sounds like i do not need to add the return. If I do so, an exeption is thrown: `java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to com.tinkerpop.blueprints.Vertex`

Comment: The used code: ` Vertex node= db.command(new OCommandSQL("UPDATE GenomeGraphNode SET seq = "+kmerasint+ " UPSERT WHERE seq = "+ kmerasint)).execute();`

Comment: The exception is because you are trying to store an integer in a vertex

Comment: thanks, but why is it an integer and not the Vertex? The manual says that the return value is the record. and the record is the vertex in my case, or not?

Comment: In according to the documentation, it return an integer because is the default return operator.

Specifies an expression to return instead of the record and what to do with the result-set returned by the expression. The available return operators are:
COUNT Returns the number of updated records. This is the default return operator.
BEFORE Returns the records before the update.
AFTER Return the records after the update.

Comment: So let's use `UPDATE ... RETURN AFTER @this`

Comment: Thanks you guys. I have test it now. For inserting 256 vertex and nearly 29000 edges i need 33 seconds. 878 records per second. I test it now with different files to see if it gets faster.
Do you have any other ideas for a better performance?